# Why is this swift code wrong?

Tags: swift, multipeer-connectivity

For some reason since I update I get the following error while working with MultiPeer connectivty I can't seem to figure it out:

> "Type MessageServiceManager does not conform to protocol MCSession"

Everything used to work perfectly, but now for some reason everything's broken and I don't know why.
this is the code it's getting all worked up about:

```
extension MessageServiceManager : MCSessionDelegate {
  func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState) {
    NSLog("%@", "peer \(peerID) didChangeState: \(state.stringValue())")
    self.delegate?.connectedDevicesChanged(self, connectedDevices: session.connectedPeers.map({$0.displayName}))
  }

  func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    NSLog("%@", "didReceiveData: \(data)")
    let str = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String
    self.delegate?.messageChanged(self, messageString: str)
  }

  func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive stream: InputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    NSLog("%@", "didReceiveStream")
  }

  func session(_ session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, at localURL: URL??, withError error: Error?) {
    NSLog("%@", "didFinishReceivingResourceWithName")
 }

  func session(_ session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, with progress: Progress) {
    NSLog("%@", "didStartReceivingResourceWithName")
  }
}
```

Comment: well, the error message tells you all you need to know: your class does not conform `MCSessionDelegate` - either use autocomplete, or manually check what does `MessageServiceManager` misses from the protocol

Comment: Nothing misses thats the proble

Answer (score 3):

You have a double question mark '??' in one of the methods.

So change this:

```
func session(_ session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, at localURL: URL??, withError error: Error?) {
    NSLog("%@", "didFinishReceivingResourceWithName")
}
```

to this:

```
func session(_ session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, at localURL: URL?, withError error: Error?) {
    NSLog("%@", "didFinishReceivingResourceWithName")
}
```

Note the removal of a '?' character after URL.

Answer (score 0):

When mentioning that:

> Type MessageServiceManager does not conform to protocol MCSession

That means that you are *not* all required methods in your class to conforms to [MCSessionDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity/mcsessiondelegate).

To solve such an issue, you could press <kbd>command</kbd> and click on `MCSessionDelegate` then select "Jump to Definition"; that should leads you to:

```
// Delegate methods for MCSession.
public protocol MCSessionDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {


    // Remote peer changed state.
    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    public func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState)


    // Received data from remote peer.
    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    public func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID)


    // Received a byte stream from remote peer.
    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    public func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive stream: InputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID)


    // Start receiving a resource from remote peer.
    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    public func session(_ session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, with progress: Progress)


    // Finished receiving a resource from remote peer and saved the content
    // in a temporary location - the app is responsible for moving the file
    // to a permanent location within its sandbox.
    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    public func session(_ session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, at localURL: URL?, withError error: Error?)


    // Made first contact with peer and have identity information about the
    // remote peer (certificate may be nil).
    @available(iOS 7.0, *)
    optional public func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceiveCertificate certificate: [Any]?, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, certificateHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Swift.Void)
}
```

which is the declaration of the protocol.

Now you could recognize what are the methods that you have to implement (all non-optional methods) or whether the method signatures are matched or not; You would notice that:

[session(_:didFinishReceivingResourceWithName:fromPeer:at:withError:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity/mcsessiondelegate/1406984-session)

is *not* implemented as it should, which is the reason of letting the complier to complains, obviously all you have to do is to implement it as:

```
func session(_ session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, at localURL: URL?, withError error: Error?) {
    // your logic goes here...
}
```